# Is it possible to use a UITableView's cells as a mask for a view underneath it?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want the background image to only be visible where the individual cells are, so as you scroll it reveals different parts of a fixed image underneath. It's basically the opposite of a common tableview with opaque cells over a background, if that makes sense.

I still want the cells to be rendered normally in addition to their edge serving as a mask boundary, since they'd have text and other subviews that aren't just for masking.

I can't find an example, but I've seen this effect before done using CSS and it looks nice. It's not incredibly complicated, but I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to do it in UIKit.

Comment: One way to do it would be to put the image in your cell and simply size and position it so it looks like its standing still as you scroll

Comment: Could you share some visual of the example you've seen in CSS ?

Comment: @Dancreek hmm, is there a way to constrain a view within a UITableViewCell relative to something outside of the tableview entirely?

Comment: @Dancreek that worked! You just have to add the constraint in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`